# Get item from list-item that is not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<ul id="component-list" class="no-left-margin">
    <li class="component-items hide">
        <span>Login</span>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            </a>
    </li>
    <li class="component-items">
        <span>Register</span>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I'm trying to get a list of items that are visible (span tags inside li tags without the hide class)

```
$('.component-items span').not('.hide');
```

The above selector is giving me an empty array.

I need the selector to give me the span tags within `<li>` without the hide class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.component-items:visible span')
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Cheers!

Comment: I did not downvote.  But if you re-read the question you can probably figure out why.

Comment: I would also like to know why the two down votes, because in my situation, there are two items in my list in the html file, then I add a few more items, the items that I add and then hide, are still selected by the other answers, but this one seems to be selecting only the visible ones. Note: the other answers are not selecting the items that were preloaded with the html, but they select the items that were hidden after adding them

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.component-items').not('.hide').find('span');
```

Comment: As I said i need the span elements, so cannot take out the span selector

Comment: Quicker -> `$('.component-items:not(".hide") > span')`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : doesn't seem to be. Try a test case at http://jsperf.com/jquery-selectot

Answer (score 0):

I like to use css pseudo class :not().

```
$(".component-items").find("span:not(.hide)")
```

Hope it helps you